# Float for 2 column layout?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Ok so I thought it would be best to work on individual parts then pull them all together in the end.

I have run into a problem when I am trying to apply all the pieces.

I have a  this is going to control the entire page padding, ect. Then I decided to make div class="nav" to contain the nav and image.

I wanted these side by side. used float:left. This works.

Then I wanted a "body" section
div class="middle" 
I wanted this to have a 2 column layout. This is where I really dont know how to go about this. I was using a float. But it didnt workout.

Then finally the div for a footer.